# Integral and measurability of a function

Tags: integration

Consider the function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ that is defined as follows:
$$f(x) = 0 \text{ if $x$ is rational and } 2^n \text{ when $x$ is irrational}$$ 
Here $n$ is the number of leading zeros in the decimal expansion of $x$ and it can take values $0, 1, ...$. Show that $f$ is measurable and calculate the value of the integral $\int_0^1 f$.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the rationals form a measure zero set.

Up to a measure $0$ set, the function is equal to
$$
f=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}2^{n-1}1_{(10^{-n},10^{-n+1})}.
$$
So it is measurable and 
$$
\int_0^1f=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}2^{n-1}(10^{-n+1}-10^{-n})=\frac{9}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2}{10}\right)^{n}.
$$
$$
=\frac{9}{2}\frac{1/5}{1-1/5}=\frac{9}{8}.
$$

Comment: Number of leading zeros in 0.01 is 1.

Comment: @pondy Edited. Let me know what you think.

Comment: It seems fine to me. The expression for $f$ that you chose is a nice one. I will wait for others to check the answer in case I am overlooking something.